# What is R.id in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a `Fragment` for which new Fragments inherit from. These inherited (child) fragments will set a layout that contains a `ListView` with id `"elements_list"`:

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false);
        }
```

This is the `onViewCreated` of the **base** Fragment

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.elements_list);
```

However I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference` when I try to invoke methods on `listView`, which means it isn't finding the `ListView` with id `"elements_list"`

So what is `R.id` and is it possible for me to pass just the name `"elements_list"` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the fragments inside a container must be identified by the `R.id.fragment_container`

But if you're are missing the R references, maybe one fix would be to rebuild the project from Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Really no idea what is it but I think that you have imported wrong R. Check in your imports on top of the class and you should import com.yourpackagename.R; I guess you are importing different R and that is why it's not finding your element.